# Shade designer Program help having trouble with both approaches of this gui program

Tags: java, swing

Shade Designer

A custom window shade designer charges a base fee of $50 per shade. In addition,
charges are added for certain styles, sizes, and colors as follows:

The object of this program with the description and the data below is to create an application that allows the user to select the style, size, color, and number of shades from list or combo boxes. The Total charges should be displayed.

Styles:
Regular shades: Add $0
Folding shades: Add $10
Roman shades: Add $15

Sizes:
25 inches wide: Add $0
27 inches wide: Add $2
32 inches wide: Add $4
40 inches wide: Add $6

Colors:
Natural: Add $5
Blue: Add $0
Teal: Add $0
Red: Add $0
Green: Add $0

I have taken two approaches and but the first program code below has a problem with the algorithim in which it doesn't add the additional cost of the styles, size and colors selection to computer the total price. I am not sure if it is a selection of each added such as total charges = styles selection + Size selection + colors selection. I am just not sure how to get this to compute and work with the correct algorithm in the code.
Code for shadedesigner.java below

The second code after this one is the second approach where a configpanel controls i beleive the list or combo box container and panels operations to the shadedesignerwindow.java. The config panel is suppose to work as a implementaton or interface for the shaddesignerwindow program. Below is what i have so far but i am not sure how to get the configpanel to work the way they want it with the shadedesignerwindow.

Below is my code that i have constructed for shadedesigner program. Everything works and complies yet I can't get the correct algorithm developed to add the additonal selections in to the total charges of the shade if a style, size and color is selected.
Repost correction 4/8/2012 edited code below.

```
   *    Filename: ShadeDesigner.java
 *  Programmer: Jamin A. Bishop
 *  Date: 3/31/2012
 * @version 1.00 2012/4/2
 */
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;

public class ShadeDesigner extends JFrame
{
    private String[] styles = {"Regular Shades", "Folding Shades", "Roman Shades"};
    private String[] size = {"25 Inches Wide", "27 Inches Wide",
                              "32 Inches Wide", "40 Inches Wide"};
    private String[] colors = {"Natural", "Blue", "Teal",
                               "Red", "Green"};
    private JLabel banner;// To display a banner
    private JPanel bannerPanel;// To hold the banner
    private JPanel stylesPanel;// 
    private JPanel sizePanel;// 
    private JPanel colorPanel;
    private JPanel buttonPanel;//

    private JList stylesList;
    private JList sizeList;
    private JList colorList;

    private JTextField Styles;
    private JTextField Size;
    private JTextField Color;

    private JButton calcButton;
    private JButton ExitButton; 

    private double totalCharges = 50.00;

    //Constants
    private final int ROWS = 5;
    private final double regularCost = 0.00;//base price for the blinds
    private final double foldingCost = 10.00;//extra cost for folding blinds
    private final double romanCost = 15.00;//extra cost for roman blinds
    private final double twentyfiveInCost = 0.00; //extra cost for 25" blinds
    private final double twentySevenInCost = 2.00;//extra cost for 27" blinds
    private final double thirtyTwoInCost = 4.00;//extra cost for 32" blinds
    private final double fourtyInCost = 6.00;//extra cost for 40" blinds
    private final double naturalColorCost = 5.00;//extra cost for color


    public ShadeDesigner()
    {
        //display a title
        setTitle("Shade Designer");

        // Specify what happens when the close button is clicked.
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // Create the banner on a panel and add it to the North region.
        buildBannerPanel();
        add(bannerPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        stylesPanel();
        add(stylesPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);

        sizePanel();
        add(sizePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        colorPanel();
        add(colorPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);

        buttonPanel();
        add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    //build the bannerpanel
    private void buildBannerPanel()
    {
        bannerPanel = new JPanel();
        bannerPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
        banner = new JLabel("Shade Designer");
        banner.setFont(new Font("SanSerif", Font.BOLD, 24));
        bannerPanel.add(banner);
    }

    //stylepanel    
    private void stylesPanel()
    {
        JLabel styleTitle = new JLabel("Select a Style.");
        stylesPanel = new JPanel();
        stylesPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5,5,5,5));
        stylesList = new JList (styles);
        stylesList.setVisibleRowCount(ROWS);
        JScrollPane stylesScrollPane = new JScrollPane(stylesList);
        stylesList.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        stylesList.addListSelectionListener(new stylesListListener());
        stylesPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        stylesPanel.add(styleTitle, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        stylesPanel.add(stylesScrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        Styles = new JTextField (5);
        Styles.setEditable(false);
        //stylesPanel.add(StylesLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        stylesPanel.add(Styles, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }
    private class stylesListListener implements ListSelectionListener
    {
        public void valueChanged (ListSelectionEvent e)
        {
            String selection = (String) stylesList.getSelectedValue();
            Styles.setText(selection);
        }
    }

    //size panel
    private void sizePanel()
    {
        JLabel sizeTitle = new JLabel("Select a Size.");
        sizePanel = new JPanel();
        sizePanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5,5,5,5));
        sizeList = new JList (size);
        sizeList.setVisibleRowCount(ROWS);
        JScrollPane stylesScrollPane = new JScrollPane(sizeList);
        sizeList.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        sizeList.addListSelectionListener(new sizeListListener());
        sizePanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        sizePanel.add(sizeTitle, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        sizePanel.add(stylesScrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        //sizeLabel = new JLabel("Style Selected: ");
        Size = new JTextField (5);
        Size.setEditable(false);
        //stylesPanel.add(StylesLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        sizePanel.add(Size, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }
    private class sizeListListener implements ListSelectionListener
    {
        public void valueChanged (ListSelectionEvent e)
        {
            String selection = (String) sizeList.getSelectedValue();
            Size.setText(selection);
        }
    }

    //color panel
    private void colorPanel()
    {
        JLabel colorTitle = new JLabel("Select a Color.");
        colorPanel = new JPanel();
        colorPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5,5,5,5));
        colorList = new JList (colors);
        colorList.setVisibleRowCount(ROWS);
        JScrollPane colorScrollPane = new JScrollPane(colorList);
        colorList.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        colorList.addListSelectionListener(new colorListListener());
        colorPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        colorPanel.add(colorTitle, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        colorPanel.add(colorScrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        //sizeLabel = new JLabel("Style Selected: ");
        Color = new JTextField (5);
        Color.setEditable(false);
        //stylesPanel.add(StylesLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        colorPanel.add(Color, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }
    private class colorListListener implements ListSelectionListener
    {
        public void valueChanged (ListSelectionEvent e)
        {
            String selection = (String) colorList.getSelectedValue();
            Color.setText(selection);
        }
    }

    //button panel
    private void buttonPanel()
    {
        calcButton= new JButton ("Calculate Charges");
        calcButton.addActionListener(new calcButtonListener());
        ExitButton = new JButton ("Exit");
        ExitButton.addActionListener(new ExitButtonListener());
        buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.add(calcButton);
        buttonPanel.add(ExitButton);    
    }

    private class calcButtonListener implements  ActionListener
    {
        //actionPerformed method parementer e an actionevent object

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
             // Create a DecimalFormat object.
             DecimalFormat dollar = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00");

             // Display the total.
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "TotalCharges: $" +
                                                 dollar.format(totalCharges));
          }
       }

       private class ExitButtonListener implements  ActionListener
       {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                //Exit the applicaiton
                System.exit(0);
            }
       }

    //static void main for the string
    public static void main(String[] args)
       {
          new ShadeDesigner();
       }
```

}

```
*   File Name: ConfigPanel.java
 *  Date: 3/26/2012
 *  Programmer: Jamin A. Bishop 
 * @version 1.00 2012/3/22
 */
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

class ConfigPanel extends JPanel
{
    private JLabel SelectStyleLabel;
    private JLabel SelectSizeLabel;
    private JLabel SelectColorLabel;
    private JPanel StylePricePanel;
    private JPanel SizePricePanel;
    private JPanel ColorPricePanel;
    private JComboBox SelectStyleBox;
    private JComboBox SelectSizeBox;
    private JComboBox SelectColorBox;

    private final int ROWS = 5;
    private final int RegShadeadd = 0.00;
    private final int FoldShadeadd = 10.00;
    private final int RomanShadeadd = 15.00;
    private final int 25inchadd = 0.00;
    private final int 27inchadd = 2.00;
    private final int 32inchadd = 4.00;
    private final int 40inchadd = 6.00;
    private final int Naturaladd = 5.00;
    private final int Blueadd = 0.00;
    private final int Tealadd = 0.00;
    private final int Redadd = 0.00;
    private final int Greenadd = 0.00;

    //create the arrays to hold the values of the combo box's
    private String[] StylePrice = {"Regular Shades", "Folding Shades", "Roman Shades"};
    private String[] SizePrice = {"25 inches Wide", "27 inches Wide", "32 inches Wide", "40 inches Wide"};
    private String[] ColorPrice = {"Nature", "Blue", "Teal", "Red", "Green"};

    // constructor
    public ConfigPanel ()
    {
        //build the panel
        buildStylePricePanel();
        buildSizePricePanel();
        buildColorPricePanel();

        //add the panel to the content pane
        add(StylePricePanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
        add(SizePricePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(ColorPricePanel, BorderLayout.EAST);

    }

    //methods to hold the strings
    public double getStylePrice ()
    {
        String selection = (String) StylePrice.getName(StylePrice);
        StylePrice.setText(selection);
    }

    public double getSizePrice ()
    {

    }

    public double getColorPrice ()
    }
}
```

the confgpanel is suppose to work with this code below

```
*   Filename: ShadeDesignerWindow.java
 *  Programmer: Jamin A. Bishop
 *  Date: 3/31/2012
 * @version 1.00 2012/3/31
 */


public class ShadeDesignerWindow extends JFrame
{
    private JLabel banner;           // To display a banner
    private ConfigPanel configPanel; // To offer various configurations
    private JPanel bannerPanel;      // To hold the banner
    private JPanel buttonPanel;      // To hold the buttons
    private JButton calcButton;      // To calculate total charges
    private JButton exitButton;      // To exit the application

    //constructor

    public ShadeDesignerWindow() 
    {
        //Title Display
        super("Shade Designer");

         // Specify what happens when the close button is clicked.
      setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

      // Create the banner on a panel.
      bannerPanel = new JPanel();
      bannerPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
      banner = new JLabel("Shade Designer");
      banner.setFont(new Font("SanSerif", Font.BOLD, 24));
      bannerPanel.add(banner);

      // Create a configuration panel.
      configPanel = new ConfigPanel();

      // Build the button panel.
      buildButtonPanel();

      // Add the banner and other panels to the content pane.
      add(bannerPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
      add(configPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
      add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

      // Pack and display the window.
      pack();
      setVisible(true);
    }

    //buildButtonPanel method

    private void buildButtonPanel()
   {
      // Create a button to calculate the charges.
      calcButton = new JButton("Calculate Charges");

      // Add an action listener to the button.
      calcButton.addActionListener(new CalcButtonListener());

      // Create a button to exit the application.
      exitButton = new JButton("Exit");

      // Add an action listener to the button.
      exitButton.addActionListener(new ExitButtonListener());

      // Put the buttons in their own panel.
      buttonPanel = new JPanel();
      buttonPanel.add(calcButton);
      buttonPanel.add(exitButton);
   }

   //calcButtonListner and calcbutton component


    private class CalcButtonListener implements ActionListener
    {
        //actionPerformed method

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
      {
         double totalCharges = 50.0;   // Total charges

         // Create a DecimalFormat object to format output.
         DecimalFormat dollar = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00");

         // Get the total charges
         totalCharges += configPanel.getStylePrice() + configPanel.getSizePrice() +
                         configPanel.getColorPrice();

         // Display the message.
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Total Charges: $" + 
                                             dollar.format(totalCharges));
      }
   } // End of inner class 

    //ExitButtonListener and exitButton component

    private class ExitButtonListener implements ActionListener
    {
        //actionPerformed method

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
      {
         System.exit(0);
      }
   } // End of inner class

   //The main method instantiates the ShadeDesigner class

    public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      ShadeDesignerWindow sdw = new ShadeDesignerWindow();
   }    
}
```

I need help trying to get either code above to work. I do not get the whole configpanel approach or what it is suppose to do. I started with the one file program because that is the way i learned java programming. Even with implemetation it was always one swing file or gui not two.
Thank you for your help.
Jamin A. Bishop

Comment: You say you do not "get" the configpanel approach -- then whose code is this? Certainly not yours.

Comment: Do you have a question?  If so, please add a '?' to it so it is easily findable.

Comment: My question is regarding the first program as into how can i fix the alogrithm so it added the selection of styles, size and color to the base charge of the shade for a total charge computation? The second question is how do i make the configpanel code implement the shadedesignerwindow code. The configpanel code is my own. The shadedesignerwindow code was given for the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just as `ConfigPanel` was factored out of the original program, pull out styles, sizes and colors as separate classes, each managing its own names and amounts. Let each of these implement a suitable interface:

```
interface MarginalBillable {
    double getMarginalCostOfCurrentSelection();
}
```

Then `ConfigPanel` can have just one method that returns the total of all current selections. For extra credit, make the parent of the three panels [abstract](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html).

```
class ConfigPanel {

    StylePanel stylePanel = new StylePanel();
    SizePanel sizePanel = new SizePanel();
    ColorPanel colorPanel = new ColorPanel();

    double getTotalMarginalAmount() {
        return stylePanel.getMarginalCostOfCurrentSelection()
            + sizePanel.getMarginalCostOfCurrentSelection()
            + colorPanel.getMarginalCostOfCurrentSelection();
    }
}

interface MarginalBillable {

    double getMarginalCostOfCurrentSelection();
}

class StylePanel extends JPanel implements MarginalBillable {

    double value;

    @Override
    public double getMarginalCostOfCurrentSelection() {
        return value; //based on current settings
    }
}

class SizePanel extends JPanel implements MarginalBillable {

    double value;

    @Override
    public double getMarginalCostOfCurrentSelection() {
        return value; //based on current settings
    }
}

class ColorPanel extends JPanel implements MarginalBillable {

    double value;

    @Override
    public double getMarginalCostOfCurrentSelection() {
        return value; //based on current settings
    }
}
```

Comment: In this context, `extends JPanel` is not required, but it illustrates that each sub-panel can have a common parent.

Comment: Thank you i will try something similar to this and see how that works out in the configpanel code.